# seperator will not work with string.Join()

Tags: string

```
const string SAVE_SEPARATOR = "#SAVE-VALUE#";


foreach (DataRow row in db.Movies.Rows)
            {

                string[] contents = new string[]{
                row["MovieName"].ToString() +
                row["Year"].ToString() +
                row["Link"].ToString() +
                row["Not"].ToString() +
                row["Downloaded"].ToString() +
                row["In Emby"].ToString()
                };

                string saveString = string.Join(SAVE_SEPARATOR, contents);
                txt.Write(saveString);
                
            }
```

I'm sure it's simple but for some reason my *savestring* will not include the *SAVE_SEPARATOR* and I have scratchted my head for hours now.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array of strings but with only one string. Replace those "+" signs with actual commas ",".